# Cron jobs got executed, but it does not show any results at destination database

Tags: python, cron

I have a Cron job that runs every 10 min on Linux (Ubuntu) machine.

```
*/10 * * * * /home/dbase/Salesforce/InsertJob1
```

When I did `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`, it displays all the records of this Cron job (InsertJob1) that has been run every 10 min.

But, when I looked at the results at the database side (Salesforce), nothing has been performed (no insertions).

On the destination side (Salesforce database), I do not see any login history of this SOAP API.

But, when I execute this Python file manually using IDE (PyCharm), it runs fine, and data gets inserted into the Salesforce database.

My questions are:

1. Do I have to modify the crontab so that it shows as `InsertJob1` instead of `InsertJob1.py`?
2. Do I have to create a **link** instead of leaving the file as `InsertJob1.py` or without extension like `InsertJob1`?
3. What other task(s) do I have beside leaving the Python file at the folder location where I pointed on Cron?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question and I don't use Python yet. Buti n general `cron` requires you to always put in the full path to the command and include the extension as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your cron:

```
*/10 * * * * /home/dbase/Salesforce/InsertJob1
```

should be

```
*/10 * * * * /path/to/env/bin/python /home/dbase/Salesforce/InsertJob1.py
```

When you run code from the terminal in a virtual environment (if you're not using one, you should consider it), you run it as

```
python script.py
```

The cron runs in much the same way, except you should specify a path to your python executable that has the appropriate packages installed.

In general, while logging for a cron job, you should have some output written to the log files that tell you whether the appropriate parts of your cron have run or not. Just add a few print() at the right places, or use the python logging module for your script.

Comment: Are you saying I should just add .py extension to current line? or I should add "/path/to/bin/python" along with what I have and .py extension?  I have other previous cron task (Python files) that are working fine withtout .py extension.